# Defining the velocity and acceleration for three dimensions

Tags: geometry

I want to know how can we define velocity in 3D? I mean that if I were to say a hypothetical body is moving at all directions simultaneously then what would it's velocity be? a vector? or a tensor? $(v_x,v_y,v_z)$ ? and how should I enter the time? and how would acceleration be like? i guess that would be tensor?
I'd appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

They are all vectors in $\Bbb R^3$.

As a function of time, the position would be a function $s:[0,+\infty)\to\Bbb R^3$.
The velocity would be its derivative (with respect to time), a function $v:(0,+\infty)\to\Bbb R^3$.
The acceleration in turn would be the derivative of the velocity (with respect to time), also a function $a:(0,+\infty)\to\Bbb R^3$.

At any given time $t$, $s(t)$, $v(t)$ and $a(t)$ are each vectors in $\Bbb R^3$.